# Are CBP officers allowed to search and clone media devices?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, electronic-items

I'm travelling to LAX and from some anecdotal horror stories I've seen online and in real life, I worry that customs officers may ask to search my laptop, seize it indefinitely and/or possibly clone the hard drive seeing as I've read that they have power to inspect you and every item when entering/leaving the United States.

I have a significant amount of pornography (all legal) on my laptop which I wonder would I have to declare to the officers as other countries such as Australia make travellers declare on arrival.

Comment: These seem to be two different questions. I suggest you remove your second paragraph and make that a separate question. BTW, yes they are allowed, but someone will give a beter answer about that.

Comment: I answered the first question, and agree with @JanDoggen that the second one should be a separate question.

Comment: First, **this is way, way overblown**.  CBP doesn't randomly search or clone devices.  This is a very time consuming and expensive process.  Everything crossing the border is subject to inspection and a laptop or phone is no different than a suitcase.  However, unless suspected or targeted for some other reason*, 99.999% of travelers are admitted with just the standard interview.  *Reasons may include canine alert, interesting travel history, drug mule profile.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The American Civil Liberties Union has a guide on [Can Border Agents Search Your Electronic Devices? It’s Complicated](https://www.aclu.org/blog/free-future/can-border-agents-search-your-electronic-devices-its-complicated) that describes current CBP policy and includes some recommendations such as encrypting your devices, and traveling with as little data as possible. They also have a guide called [Know Your Rights: What To Do When Encountering Law Enforcement at Airports and Other Ports of Entry into the U.S.](https://www.aclu.org/know-your-rights/what-do-when-encountering-law-enforcement-airports-and-other-ports-entry-us?redirect=know-your-rights/when-encountering-law-enforcement-rights-airports-and-other-ports-entry-us).

The number of searches of electronic devices has increased, up to [19,000 last year](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2017/07/14/travelers-just-won-back-a-bit-of-their-privacy-at-the-border/), but it's important to note that this is still [less than one-hundredth of one percent of border crossings](http://msnbcmedia.msn.com/i/MSNBC/Sections/NEWS/170712-cpb-wyden-letter.pdf). So while it can happen, it is quite unlikely.